# Why is my social media icons not showing in my footer?

Tags: html, css, icons, footer

Why is my social media icons not showing in my footer? Need help finding out why my social media icons are not appearing in my footer.

Instead the social media icons is appearing in the center of the page so it seems like the position has jumped out of the doc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">   
<style>
    *{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

     i {
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
         padding-left: 25px;
  }
    i.fa.fa-facebook {
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
         padding-left: 30px;
  }

    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    footer {
         background: #19252A;
    }

    ul{
        display: flex;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }

    ul li{
        list-style: none;
    }

    ul li a {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        background: #fff;
        text-align: centre;
        line-height: 80px;
        font-size: 35px;
        margin: 0 10px;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    ul li a .fa {
        position: relative;
        color: #262626;
        transition: .5s;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    ul li a:hover .fa {
        color: #fff;
        transform: rotateX(360deg);
    }

    ul li a:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #f00;
        transition: .5s;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    ul li a:hover:before {
        top: 0;

    }

    ul li:nth-child(1) a:before{
        background: #3b5999;
    }
    ul li:nth-child(2) a:before{
        background: #55acee;
    }
    ul li:nth-child(3) a:before{
        background: #cd201f;
    }
    ul li:nth-child(4) a:before{
        background: #e4405f;
    }

    .container{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
</head>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

      <footer>

        <div class="container">

                <div class="box2">
                    <p>
                        **************************************************************
                    </p>

                     <ul class=social-media-icons>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      </ul>


                </div>



        </div>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any other css imported/added? I've recreated your scenario in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfmw02pg/1/) and the icons are appearing.

Comment: It seems to work for me. I see. https://jsfiddle.net/h5vemab7/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope this help thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">   
<style>
    *{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

     i {
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
         padding-left: 25px;
  }
    i.fa.fa-facebook {
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
         padding-left: 30px;
  }

    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    footer {
         background: #19252A;
    }
    .box2 {

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;

    }
    ul{
        display: flex;
        /* position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) */
    }

    ul li{
        list-style: none;
    }

    ul li a {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        background: #fff;
        text-align: centre;
        line-height: 80px;
        font-size: 35px;
        margin: 0 10px;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    ul li a .fa {
        position: relative;
        color: #262626;
        transition: .5s;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    ul li a:hover .fa {
        color: #fff;
        transform: rotateX(360deg);
    }

    ul li a:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #f00;
        transition: .5s;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    ul li a:hover:before {
        top: 0;

    }

    ul li:nth-child(1) a:before{
        background: #3b5999;
    }
    ul li:nth-child(2) a:before{
        background: #55acee;
    }
    ul li:nth-child(3) a:before{
        background: #cd201f;
    }
    ul li:nth-child(4) a:before{
        background: #e4405f;
    }

    .container{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
</head>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

      <footer>

        <div class="container">

                <div class="box2">
                    <p>
                        **************************************************************
                    </p>

                     <ul class=social-media-icons>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      </ul>


                </div>



        </div>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```